# Hamachi on Amazon EC2 Machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, hamachi

So I tried to install LogMeIn Hamachi on my Windows Server 2008 Amazon EC2 instance, but in the middle of the install, I lost all connection to my instance. I rebooted the machine but couldn't remote desktop into it. Is there any way that I'll be able to connect to it so that I can remove Hamachi and fix my networking problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably lost the connection because Hamachi was installing the virtual network driver. If you had waited I think you could have gotten back in.

I don't know if you will be able to do anything about it if you aborted the install (which you presumably did by rebooting it) besides terminating the instance and starting over again...

Comment: Thats just what I ended up doing. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually common when installing a virtual network driver. Just give the installer 10 minutes to install and then issue a reboot via EC2 control panel, wait about 30 minutes and the server should be available. I've noticed this with both openVPN and Hamachi installations.